# What architecture should I go for do that its not a bad architecture

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I have a large form to show which can not be displayed on a single page. so what we did is divide it into 7 part, each part consist of 1 fragment and all those fragments are navigated using tab layouts and view pager. each of those fragments have their on view model in order to access data binding . Now the problem is we can randomly select any tab and update data so we need a central location to store that data and update it, but the data is complex json model so can't be stored in a database easily, is there any other option to pursue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to centralize the data then use Activity Scoped ViewModel.

Initialized your viewmodel in your fragments as below:

```
private val someViewModel: SomeViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

OR

```
private val someOtherViewModel: SomeOtherViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SomeOtherViewModel::class.java)
}
```

This way you can centralize all your data manipulation or form completion at single place.